# How to apply pagination rule when next url is not present

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-devops-rest-api, jquery-pagination

How to apply pagination rule when web page gives me data as below

{
data:[],
paging:
{
page:0,
size:100,
total_count:1190
}
}

baseurl?page=0&size=100&respose_type=json

baseurl?page=1&size=100&respose_type=json

tried few solutions by dividing total_count/size to get the pages but missed few records.Is there any option in Query parameter ?

Comment: **AFAIK**, we cannot use REST API pagination rules if we don't have next URL in our present page. However, as you know the `total_count` of pages, you can use a ForEach to loop over every page using copy activity inside ForEach.

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK**, You can use the **Range option** in the pagination.

Create a variable in the relative URL of the REST API and use that in pagination rules.

**My sample:**

**Relative URL:** `users?take=100&skip={offest}`

[image]

In Pagination rules, Give the Absolute URI and give the variable `{offset}` in pagination like below based on your requirement of page size. Here it will take 100 records and offset increases by 100 till 1190.

`AbsoluteUrl`  `{offset}`  `Range`  `0`  `1190`  `100`

[image]

For more information can go through this [ans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/723352/azure-data-factory-pagination.html) by [MartinJaffer-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/85053/martinjaffer-msft.html)